# f.when output count with Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get the total number of registered users and the total number of identified users,by month, from 2 tables that I join. See desired output:

```
Month  reg_users  iden_users
Jan       300        600
Feb       250        500
Mar       100        200
```

But I got an error:

> when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Code used:

```
#registered vs identified
dim_customers = (spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.dim_customers')
                 .filter(f.col('registration_date').between(start,end))
                 .withColumn('month', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('registration_date'), 1), 'MMM'))
                 .selectExpr('customer_id','age','gender','registration_date','month','1 as registered')
                )

df = (
      spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
     .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start,end))
     .filter(f.col('is_client_plus')==1)
     .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
     .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
     .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1) 
     .withColumn('week', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'YYYY-ww'))
     .withColumn('month', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'MMM'))
     .selectExpr('customer_id','1 as identified','date_key')
     )

output2 = (dim_customers
          .join(df,'customer_id','left')
          .fillna(0, subset=['identified'])
          .withColumn('month', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'MMM'))
          .groupby('month')
          .agg(f.countDistinct('customer_id').alias('reg_users'),
               )
          .withColumn('iden_users',f.when((f.col('identified')==1)))
          )

display(output2)
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error? A solution could be make 2 queries? My idea is to join tables and do it all together in one single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted to get the distinct count of customer ids where `identified = 1`. You can do a conditional count during the aggregation using `when`:

```
output2 = (dim_customers
          .join(df,'customer_id','left')
          .fillna(0, subset=['identified'])
          .withColumn('month', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'MMM'))
          .groupby('month')
          .agg(f.countDistinct('customer_id').alias('reg_users'),
               f.countDistinct(
                   f.when(
                       (f.col('identified')==1),
                       f.col('customer_id')
                   )
               ).alias('iden_users')
           )
          )
```